# How setup sentinel-tunnel

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I try to setup redis with two slave replicas and 3 sentinels. And I try to setup sentinel-tunnel for access to my redis. https://github.com/RedisLabs/sentinel_tunnel

what can I write in Database name?

```
{
    "Sentinels_addresses_list":[
        "node1.local:8001",
        "node2.local:8001"
    ],
    "Databases":[
        {
            "Name":"db1",
            "Local_port":"12345"
        },
        {
            "Name":"db2",
            "Local_port":"12346"    
        }
    ]
}
```

name of master from sentinel masters command? or what?

Answer (score 0):

The name is just a field for you to reference it by for convenience. Looking at the code (https://github.com/RedisLabs/sentinel_tunnel/blob/20e718c5c839a4261fc7c6bb578f4df669b08b1a/sentinel_tunnelling_client.go), that field is only used in error logging.